# Directly accessing iframe by name - is this legal?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have inherited some javascript code which directly accesses an `iframe` by its name, without any `getElementById()` or anything. I can't find any sign that this is actually legal, yet it seems to work in the browsers I've tried it in (Chrome, Firefox, IE10, Safari for Windows).

Simple test case:

```
<iframe name="iFrameName" id="iFrameId" src="test2.html"></iframe>
<button onclick="iFrameName.myFunction();">click me</button>
```

And the test2.html src of the iframe contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert("OH HAI!");
    }
</script>
```

Clicking on the button works perfectly - the alert "OH HAI" pops up.

How does this work? Should it work? Is it safe to rely on or should I be using `getElementById()` to retrieve the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does this work? Should it work?

Yes, there was a time when elements could only be accessed by name, and most (all?) browsers still support it. See the [QuirksMode page about it](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dom0.html), it was written years ago but still applies.

> Is it safe to rely on or should I be using `getElementById()` to retrieve the iframe?

You should be using `document.getElementById()` and other modern methods. If you rely on names, your code will soon become a mess.